# Как читать/записывать данные из/в текстовый файл с помощью прерываний?

Tags: linux, ассемблер, прерывания

Учу assembler, дошел до векторов прерываний. Никак не могу понять, как ими правильно оперировать. Как я понял работая с прерываниями мы должны поместить в регистры аргументы функций, и вызвать вектор прерываний. Есть вот такой код:

```
 include "io.inc"

 section .data

 file db "./Documents/file.txt",0

 O_RDONLY equ 0

 O_WRONLY equ 1

 O_RDWR equ 2

 O_CREAT equ 100o ;создание файла, если его нет

 O_TRUNC equ 1000o ;очистка файла

 O_APPEND equ 2000o ;добавление в конец файла

 section .bss

 descriptor resb 4 ;переменная для хранения дескриптора файла

 section .text

global CMAIN

CMAIN:

mov eax,5

mov ebx,file

mov ecx, O_RDONLY

mov edx, 2

int 80h ;открытие файла для чтения

mov [descriptor],eax ;сохранения дескриптора файла

…

; функции для чтения/записи файла

…

mov eax,6

mov ebx,[descriptor]

int 80h ;закрытие файла

xor eax, eax
ret
```

В принципе я смог разобраться, что в `eax` открыли поместили 8005h  открытие файла, и чтобы читать нужно поместить в `eax` 3, но как потом вывести содержимое файла на экран?

Comment: вот например https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/ (искать в гугле по "linux syscall"). Тут указано что в ebx указатель на имя файла. Для чтения в ebx дескриптор открытого файла

Comment: @Mike а как потом сохранить прочитанные данные в переменную, чтобы вывести на экран с помощью 21h?

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, под Linux не работают DOS прерывания (типа 21h).

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Посмотрите все параметры функции read, там еще передается разумеется адрес буфера куда собственно читать и сколько читать. А вывод на экран производиться таким же int 80h, причем обычной функцией write, т.е. записью в файл. Потому что экран под Linux это то же файл (с дескриптором = 1). И да, как сказали выше, никого 21h, не путайте функции ОС DOS и ОС Linux